How to edit /etc/krb5.conf from cli with crudini?
I'm trying to edit /etc/krb5.conf with crudini.
I tried this :
$ sudo crudini --set /etc/krb5.conf libdefaults renew_lifetime 7d
Source contains parsing errors: '<???>'
        [line  2]:      default_realm = myDOMAIN.LAN
$ echo $?
1
$

I expect this :
$ sudo crudini --set /etc/krb5.conf libdefaults renew_lifetime 7d
$ crudini --get /etc/krb5.conf libdefaults renew_lifetime
7d
$


Is there a stray invisible character in the file? Check with grep default_realm /etc/krb5.conf | od -c

I'm confused why this was asked here, when it was answered here a few days ago https://github.com/pixelb/crudini/issues/105
In summary the error is due to indentation, which in newer versions of crudini is supported with the --ini-options=ignoreindent option

My question on the stackoverflow forum was closed because it is dedicated to dev so I had to move it. Sorry for the inconvenience.
